# TypeScript: Enforcing both naming on keys and typing on values, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm experimenting with Angular and was wondering why I cannot enforce an object's value to be a definite type.
I'm retrieving data from a database, which eventually returns some numbers as strings; out of this I noticed actually I wasn't enforcing types on my values.
I have this interface:

```
import { Category } from './category';
import { Country } from './country';
import { Grape } from './grape';
import { Producer } from './producer';
import { Region } from './region';
import { Type } from './type';

export interface Drink {
    abv: number;
    category: Category;
    country: Country;
    description: string;
    grapes: Array<Grape>;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    producers: Array<Producer>;
    region: Region;
    reviews: Array<number>;
    type: Type;
    vegan: boolean;
    year: string;
}
```

While my drink object as retrieved from the database is typed as (example):

```
{
    abv: string;   <-----------string
    category: Category;
    country: Country;
    description: string;
    grapes: Array<Grape>;
    name: string;
    price: string;  <-----------string
    producers: Array<Producer>;
    region: Region;
    reviews: Array<string>; <------------string
    type: Type;
    vegan: boolean;
    year: string;
}
```

And I have an object called "drinks" that holds the drinks retrieved from the database (so with the string values), although the object is typed as:

```
public drinks : { [key: string]: Drink};
```

It compiles without errors. I also tried creating a dedicated interface but didn't work.

Now, since "price", "abv", and "reviews", involve numbers in the interface, it should throw an error while compiling, right? Instead I get this in chrome:

```
{
6: {
    abv:"12.5" <---------------------string
    category:{name: "sparkling"}
    country:{name: "italy"}
    description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolores adolescens eu mea. Ne cum eius necessitatibus. Ius ne ipsum fastidii dignissim. Putent nostro eu quo, vis agam mucius vocent id, cibo facilisis te pri. Libris ceteros vis te, nibh offendit no quo. Cu nec viris audiam."
    grapes:Array(1)
    0:{name: "glera"}
    length:1
    __proto__:Array(0)
    name:"prosecco"
    price:"15.00"   <-----------------string
    producers:[{…}]
    region:{name: "lombardy", countryID: "2"}
    reviews:(2) [5, "3"]  <--------------string
    type:{name: "conventional"}
    vegan:true
    year:"2016"
    __proto__:Object

  }
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing. Thank for any help. Cheers.

Comment: can you add the code that fetches the data from your db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding here is how TypeScript works. It is a compile-time check, so if you tell it a `Drink` has a number for a particular value, it enforces that type throughout your application. Again, at compile-time. So it won't allow you to pass those properties to methods that are expecting different types.

If at run-time, your API is returning strings instead of numbers, it doesn't know about that. You will have to convert them after your receive the response from the API.

Answer (score 1):

Because these type declarations are just **"type assertions"** to help the compiler understand the type of data to expect, and not **"type casts"** which would mean a run time exception generation.

A better read on this:

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html